# Sql Query to group the data from two tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `Department` and `Employee`.

**Department** table looks like this:

```
   ID     DeptName
   1      IT
   2      CSE
   3      ECE
```

**Employee** table :

```
   ID     DeptID     EmployeeName    Salary
   1       1         John            10000
   2       1         Bob             15000
   3       2         Akon            12000
   4       2         Smith           20000
```

Now I want to group the data in such a way that I get the following results which include these columns :

```
  ID      DeptName      Employee 
   1       IT            John,10000
                         Bob,15000

   2       CSE           Akon,12000
                         Smith,20000
```

Can we do something like this using SQL group functions or any other way?

Please help me.

Thanks,
Rajbir

Comment: Why did you tag this as both `sql-server-2008` and `sql-server-2005`? What version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
select final.deptId, d.deptName,
  e3.employeename + ',' + cast(e3.salary as varchar) employee
from employee e3
left join (
  select e1.id, e1.deptId from employee e1
  left join employee e2
  on e1.deptId = e2.deptId and e1.id > e2.id
  where e2.id is null
) final on e3.id = final.id
left join department d on d.id = final.deptId
```

Results in:

```
+--------+----------+-------------+
| DEPTID | DEPTNAME |  EMPLOYEE   |
+--------+----------+-------------+
|      1 | IT       | John,10000  |
|        |          | Bob,15000   |
|      2 | CSE      | Akon,12000  |
|        |          | Smith,20000 |
+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Note that the "blank" values are actually filled with `null` values.

Let me know if you have any issue with it.