# mysql, query of two linked tables returning id from first based the seconds details meeting a this but not this criteria

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am attempting to write a MySQL query that will return element whose details meet a this but not this criteria.

As an example consider a an inventory management system for office supplies. Supplies of all types would be contained within this database, and instead of creating a table with a myriad of columns each attribute of a product's description I instead did this.

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory`(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
element_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `inventory_detail`(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
element_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
label VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
attribute_string VARCHAR(255) NULL,
attribute_integer INTEGER NULL
);
```

Using these tables each product can added as inventory and it's attributes can be added as inventory detail. (ie. label = color, attribute_string = red or label = color, attribute_string != blue)
    Don't critique this method it is not what my question is about. Besides this method allows me to constantly change the number of details about a product that is stored while not having to change the database in any way.

My question is what should my query look like if I wanted to get a list of all green products that have a positive count. Basically I am looking for a query that returns element.id and the elments must be sorted by details that are excepted and ones that are not. For example:

```
SELECT element.id
FROM element
INNER JOIN element_detail ON element.id = element_detail.id
WHERE (element_detail.label = 'color'
AND element_detail.attribute_string = 'green')
AND (element_detail.label = 'count'
AND element_detail.attribute_integer <> 0);

####################################
#             INVENTORY            #
####################################
# id #           label             #
####################################
#  1 #   multi color pen pack      #
#  2 #   single pen pack (red)     #
#  3 #   single pen pack (green)   #
#  4 #   single pen pack (black)   #
#  5 #   single pen pack (blue)    #
#  6 #   single pen pack (purple)  #
####################################

########################################################
#                  INVENTORY_DETAILS                   #
########################################################
# id # element_id #    label   #    attribute_string   #
########################################################
#  1 #     1      #    color   #          red          #
#  2 #     1      #    color   #          blue         #
#  3 #     1      #    color   #          black        #
#  4 #     1      #    color   #          green        #
#  5 #     1      #    color   #          red          #
#  6 #     1      #    count   #          100          #
#  7 #     2      #    color   #          red          #
#  8 #     2      #    count   #          50           #
#  9 #     3      #    color   #          green        #
# 10 #     3      #    count   #          50           #
# 11 #     4      #    color   #          black        #
# 12 #     4      #    count   #          50           #
# 13 #     5      #    color   #          blue         #
# 14 #     5      #    count   #          0            #
# 15 #     5      #    color   #          purple       #
# 16 #     5      #    count   #          50           #
########################################################
```

A query that will return all products in the inventory and their count that have the color red but not green.

```
########################################
#              RESULT                  #
########################################
#       PRODUCT             #   COUNT  #
#  single pen pack (red)    #     50   #
#  single pen pack (black)  #     50   #
#  single pen pack (blue)   #     0    #
#  single pen pack (purple) #     50   #
########################################
```

While the mutli color pen pack has a red color pen it also has a green color pen, and should not be included in the result.

Comment: `the elments must be sorted by details that are excepted and ones that are not` -> No idea what that means. Can you provide some sample data from your tables and your expected result in a tabular format? That would help a lot. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083089/sql-query-to-group-the-data-from-two-tables)

Comment: Note that the answer to your question about returning products with 'green' isn't applicable to the other question you mentioned, about returning products that don't have 'green' even if they do have other colors. For that you'd need to do a subquery for products with 'green' and use NOT IN on that list of products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all "green" products with a positive count then you will need to join twice on the detail table

```
SELECT element.id
FROM element
INNER JOIN element_detail e1 ON element.id = e1.id
INNER JOIN element_detail e2 ON element.id = e2.id
WHERE (
      e1.label = 'color'
  AND e1.attribute_string = 'green'
) AND (
      e2.label = 'count'
  AND e2.attribute_integer > 0
);
```